# In react-native Flatlist or scrollview can we show loop like carousal?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

**I want to display an array of data in flatlist or scrollview in loop mode. I want to repeat the same array again and again. can we do that?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onEndReached` fo `FlatList` to load the data at the end. In your case,
append the same list and set the state.

> **onEndReached()**: Called once when the scroll position gets within onEndReachedThreshold
>   of the rendered conten

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {

    movies: [
      {
        name: "ajd"
      },
      {
        name: "wd"
      }
    ] 
  };

  onEndReached = () => {
    console.log('onEndReached()', this.state.data)
    this.setState({movies: [...this.state.movies, ...this.state.movies,]})
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <FlatList 
          data={this.state.movies}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return (
              <View>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
              </View>
            )
          }}
          onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```